# Recurrence relation statement

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, plane-geometry

> **Let $R_n$ denote the number of regions into which the plane is divided by n lines. Assume that each pair of lines meets in a point, but that no three lines meet in a point. Derive a recurrence relation for the sequence $R_1$, $R_2$,...**

I understand that $R_1$,  $R_2$ means the number of regions in which the plane is divided

$R_1$ is the plane divided into 1 region, $R_2$ into 2 regions

$R_1$ has one line, $R_2$ has 2 lines...
Would I have to use the formulas to find points in a plane? but I don't quite understand it, how many formulas would it be

I would greatly appreciate the help, I have to expose this exercise to raise points on this subject.

Comment: Hint: Let $R_n$ be the number of segments for n lines. Introduce a new line. How many extra parts does it introduce into the plane?

Comment: @insipidintegrator it would be that the plane is divided into even parts?

Comment: Another hint: the recurrence should be $a_n =a_{n-1}+n$.

Comment: You could also draw out the case for 1,2,3,4 lines. The no of regions follows an obvious $1+\sum_{i=1}^ni$ from there.

Comment: @insipidintegrator a user with a high reputation answered me and then deleted, said: 
**Suppose there are n lines on the plane. Now take one particular line, it divides the plane into two halfplanes. Now the n−1 other lines divide each of the half planes into Rn−1 regions, thus we have:
Rn=2Rn-1**

so would be wrong?

Comment: @Lisstalik That can be refuted by simple calculation of some initial values as was pointed out in their comments: This would imply that $R_1=2,R_2=4, R_3=8…$ but you can notice (by hand) that $R_3=7$. Take, for eg. the coordinate axes and the line x+y=1.

Comment: @Lisstalik "*R1 is the plane divided into 1 region*" $\;-\;$ How so? *Dividing* something into one piece is a contradiction of terms. Draw a line in the plane and count the regions it divides it into - that's R1 and it's quite obviously *not* 1.

Answer (score -1):

As the question itself says:

> Derive a recurrence relation for the sequence R1, R2,...

So, it means that if you draw out the cases for a few of them, you should be able to see a pattern, you have to recognise/identify that.

So, you start by drawing lines, starting from $n=1,2\cdots:$

| n | #Regions | $\sum n$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | 6 |
| 4 | 11 | 10 |

In last one, $n=4$, you have to be especially careful so that no three lines meet in a point.

As you can see, we observe a pattern coming out of it as:
$R_n=\sum n +1=\frac {n(n+1)}2+1$

And similarly the relation:
$R_n=R_{n-1}+n$ where $n\geq2$ and $R_1=2$.

Comment: I think you had better prove it by induction. A pattern which may look obvious need not be true always.

Comment: @insipidintegrator for most practical cases, it is true than not. Especially more so when the question itself states it explicitly.

Comment: The question asks for a recurrence relation, not the _solution_ of the recurrence relation.

Comment: @insipidintegrator could you please tell me the difference between the 2?

Comment: Like the relation can be $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, but its solution would be $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}\right)^n+ \left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}\right)^n\right)$ for $a_1=a_2=1$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator thanks a lot for informing.